# Download file in IntentService throw fatal exception

Tags: java, android

I am getting fatal exception while downloading file in IntentService. Little files are downloaded fine. But 9MB+- file is problem and it seems like its never ending download even on high speed WIFI connection. After few minutes there is an fatal exception. Problem part is while cycle (condition line).

Some hint please? I am missing something..

Exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[DownloadService]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:432)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.toString(AbstractStringBuilder.java:642)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(StringBuffer.java:723)
        at com.splunk.mint.network.io.InputStreamMonitor.updateBody(InputStreamMonitor.java:123)
        at com.splunk.mint.network.io.InputStreamMonitor.read(InputStreamMonitor.java:77)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:309)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
        at cz.ppmfactum.android_smartaudit.application.application.connection.DownloadService.download(DownloadService.java:103)
        at cz.ppmfactum.android_smartaudit.application.application.connection.DownloadService.onHandleIntent(DownloadService.java:46)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Code:

```
 private synchronized void download(Intent intent) throws Exception {

    String urlString = intent.getStringExtra("url");
    Log.e("URL DOWNLOAD", urlString);
    String path = intent.getStringExtra("path");
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("name") + ".temp";
    FileOutputStream output;
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    File rootFile = new File(path);
    if (!rootFile.exists())
        rootFile.mkdirs();
    File outputFile = new File(rootFile, name);
    if (outputFile.exists()) outputFile.delete();

    output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    int count;


    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }


    FileControler.renameFile(outputFile, intent.getStringExtra("name"));
    downloadedFile = new File(outputFile.getParent(), intent.getStringExtra("name"));
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: Ask the authors of `com.splunk.mint.network.io.InputStreamMonitor`, as it is their code that is crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to let you know that we're working on this issue and it will be fixed soon. For now you can just disable network monitoring by running Mint.disableNetworkMonitoring(); just before the init. Thank you for the report!

Answer (score 0):

Crash caused probably by new BugSense library called Mint... moving back for now.